# is there a way to opt out/disable further notifications in certain thread?

Tags: support, notifications

Sometimes you post an answer or a comment in a thread. Assuming the question has been answered but the OP keeps on posting comments with more requests to edit the code or answer to suit his needs. It becomes really annoying at times but some cases further comments and requests aren't  technically against the SO rules. So, is there a way to disable further notifications in certain threads?

Comment: People here are very touchy sometimes. Better change the word "thread" as Stack Overflow is NOT a forum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not that I know of sadly. Try to see if there's a [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) on the subject, if there is, vote on it, if there isn't, make a new one!

Comment: There is a more generalized request, but it does include this specific request as well. :)

Comment: thanks i have not seen the `more control over...` before asking. upvoted the other one